# SQL Server Express and created SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, etl, sql-server-express

I created with the import tool (SQL Server 2019 Express, SSMS 18.1) some SSIS import packages for testing. Now I want to delete them that they can‘t be used by accident.

Of course, I know I have no SSIS running, but when the packages are created by the SQL Server Management Studio they must be stored somewhere. How can I delete them?

Comment: The packages are saved where ever you told them to be saved. We don't know where that is, we weren't there when you chose to save the packages before you ran them to observe the location you chose.

Comment: I can only give the package a name and can‘t decide where, so I think there is a standard location.

Answer (score 2):

> I can only give the package a name and can‘t decide where, so I think there is a standard location.

By default, SSIS packages created using the Import/Export wizard are stored within the MSDB database.

[image]

To access the stored packages, you should connect to *Integration Services* from the SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

Then you should see the stored packages within the MSDB directory as shown below.

[image]

More information can be found in the following articles:

- [View packages in SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/package-management-ssis-service?view=sql-server-ver15#view-packages-in-ssms)
- [How to retrieve information about SSIS packages stored in MSDB Database](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-retrieve-information-about-ssis-packages-stored-in-msdb-database/)